# How to know from JVM stack trace that it is in GC pause

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am running kill -3 or jstack on my application, I want to know if it is in GC pause during that time, 
Is there an easy way to find out from the output?

Does it answer while in GC pause? I would expect it to work nativly some how so yes.

Comment: Well, you can at least detect whether it is running at all by looking at the GC thread status

Comment: You can watch the jstat to see if a GC has occurred around the time you perform an action.

Answer (score 2):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412303/what-does-thread-dump-looks-like-when-jvm-spent-time-in-gc) answer, maybe it answers your question. Basically, the kill -3 will wait for the GC to be completed, or get to a safe point, so you can't notice it.